# php concatenate in loop

Tags: php, loops, concatenation

I have these on my code

```
$from_m = 1;
$to_m = 6;

while( $from_m <= $to_m )
{
    if($from_m == 1)
        $m = "January";

    if($from_m == 2)
        $m = "February";

    if($from_m == 3)
        $m = "March";


    $add = "OR month = '$m' ";

    $from_m++;
}
```

as a result

```
$add = "OR month = 'March' ";
```

what I wanted is...

```
 $add = "OR month = 'January' OR month = 'February' OR month = 'March' ";
```

how can I do that way?

any help?

Comment: `$add .= "OR month = ... ";` instead of `$add = `. But that will require trimming off the first "OR" after the condition is finished, it would be better to use an array of conditions: `$conditions = array("month = 'January'", "month = 'February'", ); $add = implode(" OR ", $conditions);`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace this

```
$add = "OR month = '$m' ";
```

with

```
$add .= "OR month = '$m' ";
```

Comment: yes! it works, before I asked this question I tried $add. = ...
and I got an error. I missed a little. thanks for the help @vinay

Answer (score 0):

```
$from_m = 1;
$to_m = 6;

while( $from_m <= $to_m )
{
    if($from_m == 1)
        $m = "January";

    if($from_m == 2)
        $m = "February";

    if($from_m == 3)
        $m = "March";


    $add .= "OR month = '$m' ";

    $from_m++;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use:

```
$add .= "OR month = '$m' ";
```

instead of

```
$add = "OR month = '$m' ";
```

Comment: @metzelder check dates, I wrote this answer when there were no responses.